# Eclipse Autocompletion doesn't show function names after '.'

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, glfw

I'm using Eclipse Oxygen to create my Java program. I was trying to use `glfwCreateWindow()` to make a simple window, but Eclipse's auto-completion doesn't show the function's name (even though I imported it on second line of the picture below) in the auto-completion list :

[image: Fail completion]

The only time Eclipse suggests the function name is when I actually type out the class which contains that function (in this case `GLFW`), as seen as this second picture :

[image: Successful completion]

This is not too big of a problem, but it could be annoying when I have to type the entire class name before the function name in order for auto-completion to work. This is what I want :

[image]

Is there something I can do about this? Or will I just have to live with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the import statement from

```
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
```

to the [**static import**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html)

```
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
```

Comment: It works! Before, I didn't know what a static import is. Thanks so much!